# Trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 from USB along Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I have created the Live USB multiple times in different formats with Rufus, Unetbootin, and Pendrivelinux. I have fiddled with every BIOS setting available to me. When I boot from the USB I get a black terminal screen with a message saying "You need to load the kernel first." I cannot load into the live environment, I cannot make it to the install prompts. I've never had this on any other machine.

I am not sure how to do this, most of the answers I have read are from people who have already installed Ubuntu and are then getting this issue.

I have Windows 10 installed on my SSD, and I have a secondary 1TB HDD with an unallocated partition awaiting the Ubuntu install. I have a Gigabyte z97x-ZLI motherboard with its stock BIOS.

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with your Ubuntu ISO please verify the `sha256sum` of your iso

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed an issue with the iso file. Downloaded a fresh copy and installed without a hitch. Thanks.